# panel get unknown width

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

I have a Hgroup that contains of four panels. Sometimes it happens then when users open it the panls have a  unknown width even bigger than the window resolution.

does anyone know what the problem is or how to solve it?

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" >
    <s:Group  width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup gap="10" width="100%">
            <s:TextInput/>
            <s:Line width="100%"><s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="#696969"/></s:stroke></s:Line>
            <s:HGroup gap="20" width="100%">
                <s:Panel width="100%"/>
                <s:Panel width="100%"/>
                <s:Panel width="100%"/>
                <s:Panel width="100%"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:TextInput/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: do you want some thing like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/VkYbP.png

Comment: Do you know what happens to cause the panels to size incorrectly? I'll also add that you should not need to embed a vgroup inside a group.  You can specify a layout on the group as a VerticalLayout and remove a single container.

Comment: yes but normally it works like this, but with some users it seems that for some unkown reason the width of the panel is like 5000%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the User who was testing it was using an older version of the flash player! updating this.  fixed the problem.